# Integer Comparison Results Vary in Java

Tags: java, comparison, autoboxing

I am a novice Java programmer and came across a very weird scenario, as below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer a = 500;
    Integer b = 500;

    // Comparing the values.
    a <= b; // true
    a >= b; // true
    a == b; // false

    // Reassigning the values
    a = 50;
    b = 50;

    // Again comparing the values.
    a <= b; // true
    a >= b; // true
    a == b; // true
}
```

My question is why do the results of `a == b` vary by varying values?

Comment: That's a very classical one : small Integer are cached.

Comment: `a.equals(b)` will be `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question lies within the understanding of [Autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) specified by Java programming language.

The variation in results of `a == b` happens because any integer between -128 to 127 are **cached** by the `Integer` class. When an `int` within this range is created it is retrieved from `IntegerCache` rather than creating a new Integer object.

Is this a bug? **Of course not!**

The Java class Integer is also called **wrapper** class because it provides an object that wraps an `int` primitive data type. In Java, comparing two value object is not straight forward. We should override the `Object.equal` method (and also the `Object.hashCode`) and use it to determine when two objects are equal. Using the `==` operator, in this case, we’re comparing the two physical object addresses. Java requires the new operator to create objects, which will be all stored on the JVM’s Heap. Local variables are stored on the JVM’s Stack, but they hold a reference to the object, not the object itself.

In first case when we check if `a == b`, we’re actually checking if both the references are pointing at the same location. Answer to this is **NO!**

But what happens when a & b are 50? To answer this we should have a look at the below `Integer.valueOf` method.

```
public static Integer valueOf(int i) {
    if(i >= -128 && i <= IntegerCache.high)
        return IntegerCache.cache[i + 128];
    else
        return new Integer(i);
}
```

We are using the `Autoboxing` Java function through this `Integer.valueOf` method to compare `a == b`. With the aim of optimizing the resources use, the `Integer` class maintains a cache memory of `Integer` instances. This way, all the new Integer requests with a value between -128 and `IntegerCache.high` (configurable) will return an identical object allocated once. So, when we ask if a == b, we get true because, **behind the scene, a and b are pointing to the same memory location**.

*Now another question arises:* **Does this approach involve in instance sharing problems?** The answer fortunately is **no**, because Integer was defined as an immutable object and that means if you want to modify it, you have to get a new instance… *exciting, isn’t it*?

Shishir

Comment: @Downvoter, can you explain the reason to downvote?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but if you're not actually answering the question by providing an explanation on SO, it should probably be done in a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Michelle: Updated the answer with explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes . Because values from a range of -127 to 128 will be stored in cache . so use equals and compare .

Answer (score 1):

Java has interned the values from `-128` to `127`.

This is why you receive `true` when you compare two `Integer` objects in this range with `==`.